# Who gets the staking rewards? All committee? Or only node that proposes a block?

Tags: eth-2.0, block-reward, validators

In the new POS Ethereum 2.0, who gets the staking rewards? All committee that attested? Or only node that proposes a block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every online and active validator has to get the stacking reward, because they all contribute to the committee decision, it doesn't matter if they are the block proposer or not.

From [ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/consensus-mechanisms/pos/#pos-staking-validators) :

> Validators get rewards for proposing new blocks and for attesting to
> ones they've seen.

In a BFT consensus, the block proposer is not more important than the committee members, they all take part in the decision process. And all of them should be incentivized to follow protocol.

The block proposer will gain additional block reward :

> Once there's a crosslink, the validator who proposed the block gets
> their reward.